# Electron executing powershell script

Tags: javascript, windows, powershell, electron

I want to execute a powershell script on the start of the electron App. I tried to add the following into the `<head>` in my `index.html` :

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var spawn = require("child_process").spawn;
    spawn("powershell.exe",[".\myPSScript.ps1"]);       
</script>
</head>
<body>
...
</body>
```

This did not work. When adding:

```
document.write("Hello")
```

it shows up in the app so I can be sure that the `<script>`is being run. When I run the script itself from powershell-terminal it runs with no issues and does what it should.

I also tried giving the absolute path in:

```
spawn("powershell.exe",["C:\folder\folder2\myPSScript.ps1"]);
```

The script deletes all `.db` files in a folder on the machine.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path 'MY_Wonderfull_Path' *.db | Where-Object { $_.CreationTime -lt (get-date 2021-09-09) } | foreach { Remove-Item -Path $_.FullName }
```

I have no idea why it is not running. Is electron not able to spawn a new child process? Is it an issue with permissions?

Comment: I believe you need to double all backslashes in the absolute path: `spawn("powershell.exe",["C:\\folder\\folder2\\myPSScript.ps1"]);`

Comment: THis is right. Please make it an answer so I can approve it :)

Comment: You're right, I have now posted as answer so the question can be marked 'done'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As requested, here my comment as answer.

You need to double the backslashes in the path to escape them.

```
spawn("powershell.exe",["C:\\folder\\folder2\\myPSScript.ps1"]);
```